# pipenv: pdfkit not found when running FastAPI app

Tags: fastapi, pipenv, pdfkit, python-pdfkit, pipenv-install

I've been developing an API using FastAPI and pipenv to manage my virtual environment. To start my testing setup, I use the following commands on the console:

```
pipenv shell
uvicorn backend:app --reload
```

The API starts after a couple of seconds and everything is okay. However, recently I decided to install pdfkit to generate some PDF documents that need to be sent back to a webapp. However, after I did (using this [this page](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/) as reference):

```
pipenv install pdfkit
```

Now, whenever I try to run the same `uvicorn` command to start my API, the API returns the error `module pdfkit not found`. I've checked that the package is properly installed and it does appear on my Pipfile and whenever I type `pip freeze` once my enviroment has been activated.

Here's a snippet of the API call that returning the error:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse, StreamingResponse
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from openpyxl import Workbook
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import os

# ==========================
# SETUP
# ==========================

app = FastAPI()

# ==========================
# CORS
# ==========================

origins = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:5500/", 
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", 
    "http://localhost"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],        # List of origins that are allowed to make cross-origin requests
    allow_credentials=True,     # Indicate that cookies should be supported for cross-origin requests
    allow_methods=["*"],        # List of HTTP methods that should be allowed for cross-origin requests
    allow_headers=["*"],        # List of HTTP headers that should be supported for cross-origin requests
)

# ==========================
# GET: PDF RENDERING
# ==========================

@app.get("/pdf")
def render_pdf(pdf_content: str):
    
    from jinja2 import Template, Environment, FileSystemLoader
    import pdfkit as pdf

    # Jinja2 template "generator" or "main" object (AKA Environment)
    env = Environment(loader = FileSystemLoader('PDF Rendering'), trim_blocks=True, lstrip_blocks=True)

    # Template parameters
    template_params = {
        "BASE_PATH": os.getcwd(),
        "REPORT_CONTENT": pdf_content,
    }

    # Render template
    template = env.get_template("pdf_template.j2")
    template_text = template.render(template_params)

    with open("PDF Rendering/render.html", "w") as f:
        f.write(template_text)

    # Turn rendered file to PDF
    pdf.from_file("PDF Rendering/render.html", "PDF Rendering/render.pdf")

    return {
        "message": "Success"
    }
```

(The Jinja section works mind you, but for some reason, the pdfkit one doesnt)

Comment: It's hard to tell without the source code and the exact steps you follow...
Anyways, have you checked that the `pipenv` has the package correctly installed? Is it for the correct `python` version?

Comment: Sorry, I will include a small snippet of my code to make it clearer. But yeah. I have installed pdfkit multiple times using `pipenv install pdfkit` and that package specifically returns the error: "module not found". Something similar happened with an Excel handling package, but I manage to replace it with "openpyxl".

Comment: That's really odd...could it be that the lib did not get installed? Or is it possible that you have a folder with the same name that causes troubles?

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to check that as well, but I made sure that I dont have any folders named that way. Its just strange

Comment: And does the app run outside `pipenv` or you don't want to/can't try?